# How can I boot from that ntfs file?

Tags: filesystems, boot, ntfs, mbr

I have file system called `*.ntfs`, I ran the `file` program on this file to get information about it, and here is the output:

```
DOS/MBR boot sector...
```

I want to boot from that file system file, how can I do that? and is it dangerous? and how can I then go back to my main parttion and revert the changes?

Comment: First understand how BIOS systems, particularly Windows boot. Pictures here worth 1000+ words Older Windows but same for all BIOS versions.
http://www.multibooters.co.uk/multiboot.html  Or From BIOS firmware to MBR to PBR to load system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try but I don't think Windows will like it. You can try first with qemu, safe and you can change the drives.
If you really need to boot the real PC, you can try the grub terminal. Just store it somewhere that would be visible from grub. Reboot and enter in the grubs terminal.

```
chainloader /path/filename.ntfs
exit
```

[GRUB Manual - Chain-loading an OS](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html)

Notes:

1. File completion (TAB) should work.
2. If you want just a few files, you don't need to boot it. Just mount it with `-o loop,offset=<partition-offset>` (fdisk the file)

Comment: I still don't know how can I just extract files from this filesystem

Comment: This should be easy... Check the file with fdisk or cfdisk:

'fdisk -l file.ntfs'

if the file its ok it will work same as usual disk. This command (fdisk -l) will show you where its partition begins. You have multiply this value with 512 and use it at offset option of mount command.

'mount -t ntfs file.ntfs /mnt/mountpoint -o ro,offset=nnnnnnn,loop'

that's all, now you can see your files at /mnt/mountpoint...